# $T\colon\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^2$ Linear Transformation, finding $W$ in terms of $a, b$

Tags: linear-algebra

[Finding the definitions of T to satisfy and find the linear transformation of W.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwXcB.png)

Please see photo attached

Comment: Please share your approach and thoughts.

Comment: Note that $(2,-5,-7)=3(2,-3,-1)-2(2,-2,2)$. Can you conclude now?

Answer (score 0):

Here,the vectors ${ u,v,w }$ are linearly dependent.
Now Since we have the image of two vectors $ u,v $ which are linearly independent as they are not scalar multiple of each other.
Now take any other third vector $z (say)$ belonging to $\Bbb R^3$ such that the vectors ${u,v,z}$ are linearly independent.Define $T(z)$ to be any vector other than $T(u)$  and  $T(v) $ in $\Bbb R^2$.

Now this will give a unique linear transformation $T$ defined by

> $T(\alpha) = aT(u) + bT(v) + cT(z) $ where $\alpha$ has unique representation as  $\alpha = au + bv + cz $.

Now find scalars $a,b,c$ for $w$ and then $T(w)$